# Get child items when filtering with dropdown jqgrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I've got the following datastructure in my dropdownlist:

```
External
    Test
    Test2
Internal
    Internal2
    Internal3
```

I am trying to get both parent and child items in the grid when I select the parent item from my filter dropdown.

e.g:
When selecting External I want to get External, Test and Test2 in my jqgrid.

Is this possible in any way?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know jqgrid initialization settings, but you could do dirty hack like

```
$('parent selector').click(function () {$(this).children().click(); return true;});
```

or use jqgrid api for loading data.